# How to compare the mean to the mean of mean values of dummy variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, descriptive-statistics, binary-data, arithmetic

I am trying to validate the calculations of a mean value for a collection of binary variable values. The validation process is where I compare x to y where: x is the mean value of percentage of success to the total observed (i.e. total(1) / (total(1) + total(0))) and y is the mean value of each component in the set.

The two means are not equal! I have no idea what is wrong, I have been trying to figure it out for days now. I am speculating that I fell in a mathematical trap rather than an error in coding.

Here is the details:

| Variable | Binary values |
| --- | --- |
| V1 | 1 1 |
| V2 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 |
| V3 | 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 |
| V4 | 1 0 1 |
| V5 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 |
| V6 | 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 |
| V7 | 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 |
| V8 | 1 0 1 1 1 0 |
| V9 | 0 1 1 1 1 0 |
| V10 | 0 1 0 |
| V11 | 0 1 0 1 |

```r
Binary1 <- sum(2, 9, 7, 2, 7, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2)
Binary0 <- sum(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2)
BinaryTotal <- Binary1 + Binary0
MeanBinary1FromTotals <- Binary1/BinaryTotal
```

Now I try to validate the MeanBinary1FromTotals with the mean of means

```r
MeanV1 <- 2/2
MeanV2 <- 9/10
MeanV3 <- 7/8
MeanV4 <- 2/3
MeanV5 <- 7/9
MeanV6 <- 3/12
MeanV7 <- 4/10
MeanV8 <- 4/6
MeanV9 <- 4/6
MeanV10 <- 1/3
MeanV11 <- 2/4
MeanBinary1Sub <- mean(c(MeanV1, MeanV2, MeanV3, MeanV4, MeanV5, MeanV6, MeanV7, MeanV8, MeanV9, MeanV10, MeanV11))
```

```r
#Compare
MeanBinary1FromTotals == MeanBinary1Sub
```

The validation turns out to be false.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have

v1 = 0 1

v2 = 1 1 0 0 0 0

Total mean = 3/8

meanv1 = 1/2

meanv2 = 1/3

mean(meanv1, meanv2) = (1/2 + 1/3) / 2 = 5/12

3/8 is not equal to 5/12

Only if v1 and v2 have the same number of observations, the two means calculated would be equal.

Comment: Oh I got it now! Thank you so much Ben